# How to interpret the results of qVarselH() in qVarSel package in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, feature-selection

I tried to find the important variables for clustering using the function `qVarselH()` in `qVarSel` package like below

```
lsH <- qVarSelH(d, 10, maxit = 100)
```

And got output like below

[image]

the "x" component with non zero values indiacate the important variables? I couldnt find proper explanation in the documentation

Comment: This looks *very* broken. `$x` should be a vector of zeroes and ones, and `$ass` should be a vector of small integers up to the number of clusters. Edit your question to include version numbers of R and the package, and run the `example(qVarSelH)` to check. Its possible you've broken it by feeding it bad data, but we've no idea what your `d` is here.

Comment: I can get something like this output when I have certain rows or slices of `d` being NA values. Do you have missing data in `d`?

Comment: @Spacedman:Yes, The data has NA values and my R version is 3.3.1

Comment: @Spacedman:I ran the example(qVarSelH). Can you please tell what does the vector of 0 and 1 in $x indicates?

Comment: This is in the documentation for `qVarSelH`: `x: A 0-1 vector describing wheter variable k is selected: If  x[k] = 1 then k is selected`.

Comment: I think your problem is the NAs in your data and you should report this to the maintainer of qVarSelH